# Get the selector of a hidden button element

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer, selector

Im trying to find a selector to the following button:
[Inspecting Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OieBf.png)

I need this for a Puppeteer headless chrome task.
e.g.:  `await page.waitForSelector(The selecor comes here);`

The site: https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/
The button appears after adding a random product to cart and then redirect to: https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/kasse/anmelden

Would appreciate some help, wasted many hours trying to solve this :)

Comment: please add your code HERE. Thanks (Screenshots are illegible!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, there is no specific id to select. Here I'm trying with href attribute.

```
buttons = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/kasse/unregistriert']");
```

Now, you can do any script work with

```
buttons[0]
```